# Incorrect Function Behavior, What's Wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have created a tool that will be used in character creation for a video game.

The problem I'm having is this:

The **Warrior** and **Wizard** have 30 points *each* to spend on **Magic Power** *or* **Weapon Power**.  I tried to create a limit so that you can spend a maximum of 25 points into either Power.  What's happening is it won't let you spend the remaining 5 points in the other Power.  On top of that, it counts for both Warrior and Wizard and it should not be.  Each should have individual limits of 25.

FYI: I also put a limit on the Powers so that they can only go up to 75, which is intended.

Here is the [**CODE AND DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/oxeyeb/68/edit)

Comment: can you try isolating where exactly your problem is ... there is absolutely no way that the solution to your problem requires us to know this entire thing.  figure out what parts of your programs work/do what you want, which parts don't, find out where things go wrong/where you don't understand.  make a contrived/simplified example that demonstrates only the problem.  then post that.  see http://sscce.org/

Comment: The tool provides 30 points to spend in 2 areas, with a limit of 25 in either.  It's not letting you spend the remaining 5 points in the other area.  I can't simplify it any further.

Comment: one trivial thing to simplify would be just to only show us one "class" (warrior, wizard), because the problem seems to be the same for both.  in simplifying and refactoring your code you actually might stumble onto your problem.  EDIT: ah, didn't realize that it's the same 30 points for both classes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure from your description and a brief read that you're not properly keeping ptsSpent separate, that's all.

Comment: in any case, just test out every one of your functions to find out where the source of the problem is.  look at `add` ... it parses values, changes variables, etc.  check all of the variables at the beginning and then at the end and see if they are what you would expect them to be.  if everything behaves as expected, you know the problem isn't in `add`.  your problem has to exist somewhere.

Comment: in the case of `add`, you have multiple exit points.  add trace statements (`console.log`) to make sure that every statement that you expect to be executed is actually executed.  if you press add, you expect it to go to the end unless you can't add (too many points spent,  etc.).  Does it really go all the way to the end, or does it stop early?  why does it stop early?

Comment: JAL can you clarify?  I don't follow

Comment: Justin I don't see why you're posting me a book after you told me my 1 paragraph is too much for you to read.  The problem is not with add.

Comment: user2873008 Justin L is trying to show you how to 1) ask clearer questions and 2) suggest proper debugging and unit-test techniques. -Both of which will help you solve simple problems on your own and get better answers faster, on this site, for the hard problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JAL states `ptsSpent` is a global variable. The error occurs on Lines 30 and 32.

`if(pointsVal.value == 0 || newNumber > 75 || ptsSpent > 24) return;`

1. Consider building a 'Character' class with wizard and warrior being instances (in the scope of this example). `ptsSpent` would be a private-variable of the class.
2. The console you linked to lists "9 warnings". You might look to resolving those as well. Just good coding practice to compile cleanly, warnings are there for a reason. :)

[edit]
Basically `ptsSpent` needs to be implemented in the same manner as `weapon` and `magic` stat variables already are. Those variables are owned by the individual objects.

Comment: I'm sure yours is the correct answer but I'm not familiar with javascript.  What I've built thus far is completely from reverse engineering other tools.  What would a 'character' class look like?  This? `Character(warrior, wizard)`

Comment: See my EDIT above. You can simply follow your own examples for weapon and magic stats to refactor where ptsSpent is declared. Actually not sure how you would build the object-oriented structure in Java-script correctly. Sorry I was reading quickly and thinking in more generic terms.