# How can I limit this number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, var

My tool (below) allows a "Warrior" and a "Wizard" to **each** spend 30 points in 2 areas.

How can I limit the amount you can spend in a single area to 25, leaving 5 for the other?

**[CODE & DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oxeyeb/53/edit)**

Comment: By checking if user reached 25? It's so easy that I think it's not your code and you simply don't understand it.

Comment: @ElonThan Not only is that a bit rude, but it misses a fundamental issue with doing so - doing said "easy check" will produce *incorrect behavior*.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329916/incorrect-function-behavior-whats-wrong. Odd how this different user asks the exact same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this: [jsBin]](http://jsbin.com/ukeMiFe/1/edit), which categorizes all powers, items and gives them costs so that the logic can decide if it's affordable, usable and what the benefits are.

Comment: Very nice start. Doesn't quite work, but I like where it's going.

Comment: It's not meant to completely function. It's meant to give you ideas about how your implementation should be planned and how to rapidly deploy the basics of your app.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an implementation; but rather a notes on a workable approach.

---

Do not check if "25 points are left". Instead, limit each Class to a certain limit (e.g. 130) of power. The Class Power is the sum of the Classes' Weapon and Magic Power.

Then the Points Left is then simply "all points" minus "used points". Calculate the Points Left every time a Power Field is updated (e.g. call a `getPointsLeft()` function).

Then, Power points may always be added when:

1. The value of the the Classes' Power Fields are less than the class limit (e.g. 130)
2. *and* there are Points Left, as computed by looking at all points used

Comment: @user2811882 I look like there is an `if` missing in the `add` function  (maybe it was incorrectly put in `subtract`?) - the limit is available as `character.limits[stat]` inside those two functions.